# When is a T1 space not countably compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Can someone provide an example (preferably simple) of a T1 space not countably compact?  In case the example isn't obvious, can you pinpoint my mistake?  If a space satisfies the T1 axiom, all finite subsets are closed.  As I interpret that, the whole set is the only open set that contains the finite subsets.  So any open cover, countable or not, must include the whole set, which is a finite subcover.  Wouldn't that satisfy the definition of countably compact?  I know I'm wrong but now why.

Comment: Take $\mathbb{N}$ with discrete topology. Can you think of a countable cover that has no finite subcover?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the whole set is the only open set that contains the finite subsets" or why you think it is true.  Can you expand on that?

Comment: to Wofsey: Say X is the whole set.  I think if its topology is T1, all finite point sets are closed.  I think that means they are not contained in any element of the topology except X.  Is that my mistake?  The T1 definition I have is from Munkres: "The condition that finite point sets be closed is in fact weaker than the Hausdorff condition. For example, the real line in the finite complement topology is not a Hausdorff space, but it is a space in which finite point sets are closed. The condition that finite point sets be closed has been given a name of its own: it is called the TI axiom."

Comment: To freakish: Would the discrete topology on N be T1?  Wouldn't the subset {7} be a finite open subset?

Comment: Of course it's $T_1$, precisely because each point is open.

Comment: You seem to think that finite sets being closed means that it is not allowed for them to also be open.  This is false.

Comment: To Randall & freakish: Maybe I understand.  In discrete topology {7} would be closed, as would any finite subset of natural numbers.  Is that right?  If that's right, then that would be the example I was looking for.

Comment: Correct:  in fact, all subsets are both open and closed.

Comment: The same would be true for the discrete topology on any set, would it not?  Is there a way for me to acknowledge the help other than this comment?

Answer (score 3):

Take $\mathbb{N}$ with discrete topology. Of course it is a $T_1$ space just like every discrete space. Now consider $\mathcal{U}=\big\{\{n\}\big\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ which is a countable cover of $\mathbb{N}$. But does it have a finite subcover? Or any subcover?